# Can I somehow make UINavigationBar looks like iOS 6 UINavigationBar in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, uinavigationbar

Can I somehow make `UINavigationBar` looks like iOS 6 `UINavigationBar` in iOS 7 and iOS 8 (with blue background color, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm ashamed to admit it but we did a similar thing for one of our Apps as the client was not willing to do a redesign.

You will need your designer to get you the blue tinted navigation bar as an image that you can set as the navigation bars background. As for the back buttons and other items you will need all the resources as well to be able to replicate those.

So if you are looking to change it in code this is unfortunately not possible.